# Error while importing Liferay lar project

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay to develop a website.
In Site Administration, under Site Pages, I am trying to import a .lar file.
I selected the lar file and then when I click on import after following the steps, the import is failed and the error message that I get is :

An unexpected error occurred with the publication process. Please check your portal and publising configuration.
com.liferay.portlet.journal.DuplicateArticleIdException

I have tried importing the lar file several times but I get this same error message evrytime

What is the cause for this and what should be done?

Comment: Are you trying to import pages along with other data,because if you need only the pages,you can uncheck the data field,while importing the lar.It seems some existing content is being imported by the lar,which is leading to duplicate id exception.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal : Thanks for the reply. I need only the pages to be imported. Each page has web content display and theme. These web content display will be modified later by the user. I did not find the data field check box. Can you tell me where exactly I can find the data field while importing the lar file

Comment: Yes,after clicking on import,in the import dialog box,under applications,just uncheck data and try again.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal : I will note the steps I followed since I cannot find the data field.
I am using liferay 6.2 and I clicked on Import and the dialog box appears. There are many radio button oprtion. Among them there is All Applications and Choose Applications.In both of them, I did not find data field. I searched in other places but there is not data field.

Comment: Okay..try unchecking content or all application or both,if there.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal:
 THere is a radio button for All Applications and Choose Applications and another radio button for All Content and Choose Content. Under Choose COntent there re various checkboxes like wiki, web content etc. but there is no Data checkbox

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal : Is there some other way?

Comment: Okay..so the thing is you have to uncheck all other content so after selecting choose content,just uncheck everything including wiki,web content

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal : Yes. THe import was successful. Thanks Shivam. Where should I find the pages now? Doesn't show anywhere.. :)

Comment: Got that :) Thanks . I will upvote your answer

Comment: Thanks!Good it works for you

Comment: PLease make it as your answer so I can upvote it and accept.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal : I have one doubt. Since I unchecked all those fields, wil it affect when the end user uses it? Becuse the end user is a non developer.

Comment: Basically by importing these pages(without content included),all the required pages are created but any other data such as any wiki,blog,web content or forum is not imported,so if the end user needs just the pages,with your portlets on it,it will work just fine!!

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal : The import is successful but the data of web content portlet is not displayed on the page. Only theme and empty we content portlets appear. What if I want the content data? PLease note that the project import fails if I dont uncheck all options of Contetn and Applications.

Comment: It seems some of the content you are trying to import already exists in portal.Try out this..try                                        1)export your current data from portal 2)delete existing content 3)try importing with checkboxes checked now

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal : Thanks.. IT got imported successfully with few issues..

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal Thanks a lot!! It works

Comment: Will add this as future answer reference.

Answer (score 0):

Collating all comments in a single answer,try out with these given scenarios

1. Unchecking content or all application or both,if there
2. You have to uncheck all other content so after selecting choose content,just uncheck everything including wiki,web content
3. By importing these pages(without content included),all the required pages are created but any other data such as any wiki,blog,web content or forum is not imported,so if the end user needs just the pages,with your portlets on it
4. It seems some of the content you are trying to import already exists in portal.Try out this..try 1)export your current data from portal 2)delete existing content 3)try importing with checkboxes,checked

Answer (score 0):

Create new database and import your dump to the new database.and try importing LAR file.